# powershell command execution progress?

Tags: powershell, progress-bar

So I am doing some file operations using powershell using a combination of commands.

eg:

```
import-csv $DataFile -Delimiter "`t" | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation | % { $_ -replace '"', ""} | out-file $PipeFile
(get-content $DataFile -ReadCount 1000) -replace '\x00','' | set-content $DataFile
```

and a few more file manipulations.

These manipulations are happening on huge data files which take 40-60 minutes to execute. So, we wanted to see some kind of "progress bar or progress meter" that will allow me to identify how much is completed vs pending. Or something verbose that can be put on the screen?

write-progress is something I thought would help me, but, how I am interpreting it is better suited for "loops".

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`Write-Progress` IS more suited to loops, however you can still use it.

I've just attempted to edit your code so that it uses foreach loops to write out progress.

You will have to test this in a safe environment.

```
# Grabbing pipe data
# ------------------

$PipeData = Import-CSV $DataFile -delim "`t" | ConvertTo-Csv -delim '|' -notype

ForEach ($line in $PipeData)
{
    $New_PipeData += $line -replace '"', ""
    Write-Progress `
      -id 1 `
      -Activity "Creating New Pipe Data" `
      -Status "Converting..." `
      -PercentComplete ($progress/100))
    $progress += $line.length
}

$New_PipeData | Out-File $PipeFile

# Writing out to data file
# ------------------------

ForEach ($block in ((gc $DataFile -ReadCount 1000) -replace '\x00',''))
{
    $block | set-content $DataFile
    Write-Progress `
      -id 2 `
      -Activity "Outputting blocks" `
      -Status "Writing..." `
      -PercentComplete ($progress/100)
    $progress += $block.length
}
```

There is a high chance that you will need to tweak this to suit your needs.

Comment: wow. I never thought this could be so useful. I will try it tomorrow and update here. Thanks @vasiliSyrakis